# Create tree structure from nested list objects

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

I have the following class:

```
  public class  MyObject {
  String name;
  List<MyObject> myObjectsList;// it contains nested MyObject references sometimes also in cyclic manner. 
}
```

In my `Main` class I have populated a list `List<MyObject>`.
 The objects in this list have to be printed in tree-like structure.
 What algorithm can I use in order to achieve this?

Comment: So is there any reason for myObjectsList to be a list? Is there a sequential order there? Have you done a google search so far for how to do this? Basically what have you tried so far to solve this?

Comment: myObjectsList is list because multiple objects must be stored. There is no sequential order. I've searched in google but didn't found anything  usefull And I have no idea from where to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add print method to your class. Example method

```
public void print(int level)
{
    // print own name
    String branch = "|";
    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
    {
        branch += "-";
    }
    System.out.println(branch + name);

    // print names from list
    if (myObjectsList != null)
    {
        for (MyObject m : myObjectsList)
        {
            m.print(level+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Test

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
    myObj.name = "Name00";
    myObj.myObjectsList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

    MyObject tmp1;
    MyObject tmp2;

    tmp1 = new MyObject();
    tmp1.name = "Name10";
    myObj.myObjectsList.add(tmp1);

    tmp1.myObjectsList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    tmp2 = new MyObject();
    tmp2.name = "Name20";
    tmp1.myObjectsList.add(tmp2);

    tmp2 = new MyObject();
    tmp2.name = "Name21";
    tmp1.myObjectsList.add(tmp2);

    tmp1 = new MyObject();
    tmp1.name = "Name11";
    myObj.myObjectsList.add(tmp1);

    tmp1 = new MyObject();
    tmp1.name = "Name12";
    myObj.myObjectsList.add(tmp1);

    myObj.print(0);
}
```

Result

```
|Name00
|-Name10
|--Name20
|--Name21
|-Name11
|-Name12
```

Now you can modify it in the way you want to